# como poner mi propio tema de wordpress por defecto

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que consiste en una tienda online con wordpress y woocommerce. En un primer momento, comencé a desarrollar el tema totalmente personalizado desde cero. Después, instalé woocommerce y estudié todo lo relacionado con los childthemes.
El caso es que en un principio todo va bien sin haber tenido que instalar ningún tema hijo, simplemente estoy haciendo lo que dice la documentación de wordpress: crear un archivo functions y ahí sobreescribir los templates de woocommerce que necesite. Además de tener mi propia hoja de estilos.
Hasta aquí ninguna duda. Pero hoy veo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Tengo que poner mi tema por defecto? Si es así, ¿cómo se hace?
¿Realmente es un problema serio o es algo que detecta wordpress y lanza el aviso por defecto?
Gracias!

Comment: es algo que avisa wordpress.. por defecto podes poner cualquiera que no sea el tuyo.. si el tuyo falla por algun motivo, se activa ese...

Comment: es para cuando hay errores graves, podes dejar uno de los `twenty...` o setear un [`define( ['WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'tu-default-theme-quenohacenadalocoquepuedarompertodo' );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Themes_Screen#Default_Theme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no es un problema, es solo una medida de seguridad en caso de que tu tema falle, bastaría con que te descargues otro tema o dejes en la carpeta themes un tema de wordpress, ya que seguramente esa adventencia es porque solo tienes un tema en tu instalación, como dato extra, en la base de datos de wordpress, en la tabla wp_option puedes establecer un tema por defecto en el apartado de témplate agregando el nombre del tema, o bien estableciendo desde el archivo wp-config.php como lo explico @aloMalbarez